# Nested Quantifiers:Is this solution right?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, quantifiers

I need to express this system specification using quantifiers and predicates.

*The email address of every user can be retrieved whenever the archive contains at least one message sent by every user on the system*

Here are the predicates i used

$S(m,x)$ = message $m$ is sent by user $x$

$A(a,x)$ = $a$ is the email address of $x$

$C(m)$ = archive contains message $m$

$U(x)$ = user $x$ is on system

$R(a)$ = email address $a$ can be retrieved

Here is my answer

$\forall x [(U(x) \rightarrow \exists m (C(m) \land S(m,x)) \rightarrow \forall a (A(a,x) \rightarrow R(a))]$

Is this solution right?

Comment: You have overloaded S for two predicates.  Use distinct letters.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have changed it. Please tell me is this solution right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$\forall x~[(U(x) \rightarrow \exists m~(C(m) \land S(m,x)) \rightarrow \forall a~(A(a,x) \rightarrow R(a))]$$

This says: The email address of *any user* can be retrieved *whenever* the archive contains at least one message sent by **that user** on the system.

You wanted to say: The email address of *every user* can be retrieved *whenever* the archive contains at least one message sent by **every user** on the system.

That is not *quite* the same thing.

Comment: Will you suggest any solution? What should I change in this proposition?

Comment: You have said "*Any user* (can do this if *that user* can do that)."  You want to say "(*Every user* can do this) if (*every user* can do that)".  The distinction should be clear.

Comment: Thanks a lot Graham Kemp